# Enviar valores POST automaticamente al escribir en un input mediante FETCH API y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, fetch

Tengo un input text con la funcion onInput que detecta el valor ingresado

```
<input type="text"  name="cod" id="cod" oninput=codigo(this.value) autocomplete="off">
```

Igualmente una funcion que devuelve dicho valor

```
function valor(codigo) {
  var resultado = cod;  
  console.log(cod); 
}
```

Por otra parte cuento con un archivo php, que de momento toma el valor del input y lo retorna

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['cod'])) {
    $cod = $_POST['cod'];

    echo json_encode($cod);
}
```

Lo que busco hacer es tomar el valor escrito en el input, procesarlo con php, retomarlo y mostrarlo mediante fetch API, mi codigo completo se veria algo así:

```
 function valor(codigo) {
      var resultado = cod;  
      console.log(resultado); 


  fetch("buscar.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: resultado,
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

No sé que estoy haciendo mal, porque mi archivo php no recibe ningún dato, de antemano gracias

Comment: Donde se encuentra tu función código?, no la haz escrito en la pregunta, ademas... creo que no es buena idea esto, es decir, serian muchas consultas por cada vez que escribes...

Comment: La función `valor` defines la variable `codigo` como parámetro, pero internamente usas solo `cod`. @Riven, un uso de esto puede ser para un campo con autocompletado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oninput="codigo(this.value)"

Se escribe entre comillas y porque no un

```
document.getElementById('cod').addEventListener('change' ()=>{
  resultado = new FromData(document.getElementById('cod'));
  fetch("buscar.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: resultado,
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
})
```

Puedes minificar el document.getElementById('');

de la siguiente forma y te hara la vida mas facil

let id = nombre => document.getElementById(nombre);

puede quedar así sin () y sin {} pues es una arrow function que solo autoretorna una funcion digamoslo asi y obtiene un solo parametro con eso puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
let id = nombre => document.getElementById(nombre);

id('cod').addEventListener('change', ()=>{
    datos = new FormData(id('cod'));
    fecht('buscar.php', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: datos
  })
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res =>{
     console.log(res)
  })
})
```

Comment: Resuelto amigo, muchas gracias